# Issue installing geoplot package

Tags: python, geospatial, geoplot

When I try to install geoplot in either my Linux box or windows box the terminal either gets hung up or I get an [error: unable to determine GEOS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52wiC.png) . I checked geos version in anaconda and it states I have [GEOS 3.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mauAe.png).

I've tried both `pip install geoplot` and the line provided on the conda-forge site for geoplot `conda install -c conda-forge geoplotlib` .

I've searched for a solution for the past couple hours, but no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a frequent issue faced by most of the developers trying to install GEOS, Cartopy and Proj.

It happens to be that there are certain packages that need to exist before installing GEOS or Cartopy. A quick look at your screenshot of the error, you can try out the following...

```
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev proj-data proj-bin  
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev  
sudo pip install cython  
sudo pip install cartopy
sudo apt install python3-dev
```

---

An alternative solution in case above does not work for you, the reason could be of a mixed channel problem in Anaconda, to resolve that, issue following commands as root (admin)

```
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

edit the ~/.condarc file which will look like this after the edit:

```
channel_priority: strict
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
```

Use the root user to install it because it will have to access places where your standard user does not have access.

```
conda install geoplot -c conda-forge
```

Answer (score 0):

I suffered with the same issue, but was able to resolve it by creating a geo_env (https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html) and then running conda install geoplot -c conda-forge